# Expression not evaluated at callback statement

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback

I am building a GUI in Matlab that plots different functions in different plots according to the selected `RadioButton`. It looks like:

[image: GUI]

I want to select at which `axes` should the function be plotted. Therefore I need to know which of the `RadioButton` is selected. Then:

```
% Set default RadioButton
set(h.r1,'Value',1);
set(h.r2,'Value',0);

set(h.r1,'Callback',{@myRadioButton, h.r2}); % Set the other RadioButton to false
set(h.r2,'Callback',{@myRadioButton, h.r1}); % Set the other RadioButton to false
```

Then I call press one of any `Button` and call my plotting function which (should) evaluate(s) which `axes` it has to use:

```
set(h.b1,'Callback',{@myPlotFunction,...
   get(h.r1,'value')*h.axes1+get(h.r2,'value')*h.axes2, h.x});
```

The problem is that I always get `h.axes1` as input, no matter which `RadioButton` I choose.

Is this due to the definition of default values for `RadioButton`?

Answer (score 0):

### **EDIT**

Another edit: Ok, now we're dynamically assigning the button handles and xdata inside of the radiobutton callback.

Due to some peculiarities with MATLABs handling of function handle arguments (see comments), my first answer doesn't work. This one does.

```
set(h.r1,'Callback',{@TurnOffRadio, h.r2, h.axes1, h.x});
set(h.r2,'Callback',{@TurnOffRadio, h.r1, h.axes2, h.x});


function TurnOffRadio(hObject, eventdata, radiohandle, axeshandle, xdata)
    set(radiohandle, 'Value', 0);
    set(h.b1,'Callback',{@myPlotFunction, axeshandle, xdata});
    %// Repeat set statement for each button.
end    %// You may nee to remove this end, depending on your conventions.

function myPlotFunction(hObject, eventdata, axeshandle, xdata)
    %// do whatever here with axeshandle and xdata.
end    %// You may nee to remove this end, depending on your conventions.
```

I've set up a toy example and run this exact code, and it produces the desired effect.

Let me know if this still doesn't solve the problem, and I'll keep digging.

---

### Original

You're close. The problem is that when you set a callback function using a function handle and arguments, the arguments always remain what they were at the time that the callback was set. Essentially, they are passed only once, not dynamically each time the callback is executed. To work around this, just set the callback to turn off the other radio button directly using `set`.

```
set(h.r1,'Callback',{@set, h.r2, 'Value', 0});
set(h.r2,'Callback',{@set, h.r1, 'Value', 0});
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I substituted my `RadioButton`'s callback but that did not solve my problem. When I select the other `RadioButton` I get: `Invalid parameter/value pair arguments 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback`

Comment: Hmmmm, ok, I must have made a mistake. Let me look into it. That probably means radiobuttons don't use the value/logical assignment pair, which was an assumption I made.

Comment: Ok, this problem stems from MATLABs peculiar handling of function handle arguments. When you pass a arguments through function handles, MATLAB adds a hObject and Event variable. 'Set', being a default function can't handle that, so we need to construct a passthrough function. I'll post the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: it tried the `%end` tip but it didn't work as well. I am able to change the `RadioButton` but not the `axes`

Comment: Ah, yep, it's the same issue in the other `set` statement for the axis. Whatever the handle value is at the time that the callback is assigned will be what it is all the time. I'll update my answer.

Comment: i saw that u edited your question, but I don't see no difference

Comment: I also though about that. It seems that a dynamic assignment is not possible in that line of code. In that case, I'd rather check which `RadioButton`is activated when clicking a `Pushbutton`

Comment: Hm, well man I don't know what to tell you. It's working for me in a toy example. I agree that choosing the axis after push button is more elegant, but I can't think of how you'd do it. Maybe using `getappdata()` and `setappdata()`...